# if statement selects switch statement

Tags: php, if-statement, switch-statement

I hope this makes sense. Right now I am using the following code to add up number of checkboxes check and get a shipping price based off that number. This only gets me one set off shipping prices (ground). I know want to add mulitpble shipping options so I need to add another set of switch/case statement.

```
//Add up club totals for shipping
            $clubTotal = array(
                            $driversChecked,
                            $hybridsChecked,
                            $woodsChecked,
                            $boxesChecked,
                            $wedgesChecked,
                            );  

            //see what shipping was picked
            $shippingChoice = $_POST['ShipMethod'];

            //Figure out ground shipping
            if (array_sum($clubTotal))
            {
                switch(array_sum($clubTotal))
                {
                    case 6:
                        $shippingCost =  15.99 ;
                        break ;

                    case 7:
                    case 8:
                        $shippingCost =  16.99 ;
                        break ;

                    case 9:
                    case 10:
                        $shippingCost =  17.99 ;
                        break ;

                    case 11:
                    case 12:
                        $shippingCost =  18.99 ;
                        break ;

                    case 13:
                        $shippingCost =  19.99 ;
                    break ;

                    case 14:
                        $shippingCost =  20.99 ;
                    break ;

                    case 15:
                        $shippingCost =  21.99 ;
                    break ;

                    case 16:
                        $shippingCost = 22.99;
                    break ;

                    default:
                        $shippingCost = 14.99;
                        break ;
                }
            }
```

If `$shippingChoice = $_POST['ShipMethod'];` is getting my ship method, how can I use that to select what switch/case statement to use. Like if `$shippingChoice` returned the value of "ground" it would use my current switch/case statement.If it returned "2 Day" it would use another switch/case statement I would make.

Comment: I don't see a point to this switch statement. Why are these shipping cost values not present in a stdClass that you can reference the value based on the array key, which based on your structure, would be something like 1-16?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like this? Add a subarray for other shipping methods.

```
$shippingCostData = array(
    'ground' => array(
        6 => 15.99,
        7 => 16.99,
        8 => 16.99,
        9 => 17.99,
        10 => 17.99,
        11 => 18.99,
        12 => 18.99,
        13 => 19.99,
        14 => 20.99,
        15 => 21.99,
        16 => 22.99,
        'default' => 14.99,
    ),
);

$method = 'ground';
$clubTotalSum = array_sum($clubTotal);
$shippingCost = (isset($shippingCostData[$method][$clubTotalSum]) ? $shippingCostData[$method][$clubTotalSum] : $shippingCostData[$method]['default']);
```

You can also use something like this to filter shipping methods to make sure it is valid.

```
$method = (isset($shippingCostData[$_POST['shippingMethod']]) ? $_POST['shippingMethod'] : key($shippingCostData));
```

Comment: What I dislike about this approach is that you must make sure you have populated the costs array up to the maximum possible sum, otherwise the code will work but do the wrong thing (return the "default" value).

Comment: @Jon but it is simple to understand, simple to use. KISS.

Comment: KISS is not an excuse to invite bugs, especially where money is concerned. It would be easy to adapt this so that there is no chance of such a problem, and IMO you should.

Answer (score 1):

You should define the shipping charges in another form that is more malleable at run time. For example:

```
$costs = [
    1 => 14.99, // 1 or more = 14.99
    6 => 15.99, // 6 or more
    7 => 16.99,
    9 => 17.99,
];
```

You can then write a function that takes the number and the costs array and returns the cost:

```
function calculateCost($items, $costs) {
    ksort($costs); // just to be on the safe side
    $result = reset($costs);
    foreach($costs as $number => $cost) {
        if ($number > $items) break;
        $result = $cost;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

After you have done this, it's easy to keep multiple costs arrays and forward to the one you need, e.g.

```
$costs = [
    'ground' => [
        1 => 14.99,
        6 => 15.99,
    ],
    'air' => [
        1 => 24.99,
        6 => 25.99,
    ],
];

$shippingChoice = $_POST['ShipMethod'];
$cost = calculateCost(array_sum($clubTotal), $costs[$shippingChoice]);
```

You can easily extend this to as many shipping methods as you like.

Comment: I tried that code and it seems to be breaking. I guess the only part I dont understand is the `function`. Should i define `$items` be equal to the number of checkboxs checked??

Comment: @Packy: Basically to whatever `array_sum($clubTotal)` is. "Items" was my interpretation of it.

Comment: Thats what I thought and I defined $items as that but still breaking. Right now I have the `$costs` array, the `$shippingChoice`, the `$cost` then the `function`. Is that the right order? I am not sure the `$number` part of the function.